# jQuery UI Sortable and Draggable scrolling issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

we're working on creating an interface similar to a simple video creator (like Windows Movie Maker or iMovie), and we're running into trouble with our timeline-esque thing.

Basically, we have a set of clips that can be dragged (using jQuery UI's Draggable module) to a timeline area (a jQuery UI Sortable div). The gist of what we're trying to do is posted at this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dkuntz2/28EH5/3/, or below.

The problem we're encountering is that when you drag a clip from the main clips section to the timeline, and drag over, attempting to scroll on the timeline, not the whole page, the entire page scrolls, but only if you start while hovering on the timeline. To see this, the timeline needs to be larger than the `timelineNcommands` div. It's weird, and we don't like it.

We tried to implement the solution given at [Jquery UI draggable not scrolling the sortable container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241994/jquery-ui-draggable-not-scrolling-the-sortable-container), but couldn't get it to work. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

// HTML

```
<div id="storyboard">
  <div id="clips"></div>

  <div id="timelineNcommands">
    <div id="timelineCommands"></div>
    <div id="timelineHolder">
      <div id="timeline"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

// JavaScript (needs jQuery 2 and jQuery UI 1.10)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#timeline").sortable({
    scroll: true,
    axis: 'x',
  })

  $("#timeline").on('sortreceive', function(event, ui) {
    setTimelineWidth(0);
  });

  $("#timeline").on('sortover', function(event, ui) {
    setTimelineWidth(70);
  })

  var clipNums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  

  $.each(clipNums, function(i, num) {
    var div = $("<div/>", {
      class: 'clip',
      id: 'clip-' + num
    }).html(
      "<h2>" + num + "</h2>"
    )

    div.appendTo('#clips')
    div.draggable({
      revert: "invalid",
      scroll: false,
      helper: "clone",
      connectToSortable: "#timeline",
      containement: '#storyboard',

      helper: function() {

        $("#storyboard").append(
          '<div id="clone" class="clip">' + 
          $(this).html() + '</div>'
        );

        return $("#clone");
      }
    })  
  })
})

function setTimelineWidth(extra) {
  if ($("#timelineNcommands").width() < ($("#timeline").sortable('toArray').length * 70) + extra)     
    $("#timeline").width(($("#timeline").sortable('toArray').length * 70) + extra + "px")
  else
    $("#timeline").width("220");
}
```

// CSS

```
#storyboard #clips {
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
}

#storyboard .clip {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #d4d0ad;
  border: 10px solid #d4d0ad;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  z-index: 10;
}

#storyboard .clip h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
}

#storyboard .clip p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#storyboard #timelineNcommands {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 220px;
  background: #f8f7f1;
  border: 5px solid #dddabe;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#storyboard #timelineNcommands #timelineHolder {
  margin-left: -5px;
  min-width: 100%;
}

#storyboard #timelineNcommands #timeline {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```